# Strongly Attributed Property in Master View Becomes Null After Callback Delegation from Detail View in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a Split View Controller with the master view containing a Tab Bar Controller, whose four tabs are each controlled by separate "MasterViewController" objects, which delegate to the detail view:
[image]

The MasterViewController class is as follows:

```
@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar; // Not pictured above
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *displayData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *auditedData;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; // Each of the tabs contains a tableview
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *itemCounter;

@end
```

and is initialized as follows:

```
MasterViewController *blahMasterController = (MasterViewController *)tabItem;
blahController.displayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
blahController.delegate = detailTableViewController;
blahDetailController.recallDelegate = blahController;
```

Functionality is such that when a user selects a table row in one of the tabs, the relevant data is displayed in the detail view controller.  Then, when the user taps a button on the detail view controller, the entry in the master view tab is removed.

The former works well...the later is behaving strangely.  Here is my "respondToDetailViewButton" method in the MasterViewController (the method delegated to by the detail controller):

```
- (void)respondToDetailViewButton
{
    NSLog(@"Class: %@: %@", [self class], self);
    NSLog(@"TableView: %@", self.displayMachinesTableView);
    NSLog(@"Search Bar:%@", self.searchBar);
}
```

and its output:

> Class: MasterViewController: /MasterViewController: 0x105b10a0/
>   TableView: /UITableView: 0xe960c00; frame = (0 0; 320 395);
>   clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers =
>   ; layer = /CALayer: 0x114b9950/; contentOffset:
>   {0, 0}/
>  Search Bar: (null)

From the above you can see that when the detail controller delegates back to its master, the searchBar reference, despite being strongly attributed, becomes null despite the references to MasterViewController's tableView remaining intact.

And the searchBar is verifiably non-nil at some point because in the MasterViewController object, the following call in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
currentScope = [searchBar.scopeButtonTitles objectAtIndex:searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];
NSLog(@"%@", currentScope);
```

renders "New" or "Old" or "Blah" depending on the scope I have selected.

Does anyone have an idea as to why the searchBar reference becomes null based on what I have provided? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I wasn't sure what else might be helpful to add as the post had already grown pretty long.  Please ask for more details that you think would help you diagnose the issue I am having.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the idSearchBar property ever non-nil? Just because it shows in the UI doesn't mean the IBOutlet was hooked up to have a pointer to the UISearchBar object

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have updated my question towards the end to verify that the searchBar is not always nil

Comment: That does not prove that self.idSearchBar is non-nil. In your example you use "searchBar" which I am assuming is a local variable. How did that local variable get initialized?

Comment: its @synthesized from the header file. (In my project it is called idSearchBar; I was trying to make it as general as possible and remove the 'id' part from its name for this question, but did not edit that out in time.  Sorry for the confusion)

Comment: To be clear: searchBar is the @property, which is synthesize'd, and is the same searchBar referenced by self.searchBar

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment conversation under the question one possibility is that inconsistent variable naming might be the problem. It looks like you might have "@synthesize idSearchBar = searchBar;" in your implementation so self.idSearchBar and searchBar are effectively the same thing.

The problem with this is a local variable called searchBar somewhere else in your class could overwrite your instance variable. So try this: Change the synthesize line to "@synthesize idSearchBar = _idSearchBar;" or remove the @synthesize line completely and let the compiler auto-generate that exact line for you (if using LLVM compiler 4.0). Change all searchBar usage that show up as an error to "self.idSearchBar" to be consistent throughout your class. Any leftover uses of searchBar will be local variables that should not be changed.

After that - do you still see the problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as "searchBar" in my class.  I confused you by accidentally copying over 'idSearchBar' and forgetting to remove the _id_ prefix in my question (for generality).  All are "idSearchBar" and result from synthesize.  All references to idSearchBar in my class.m follow:
@synthesize idSearchBar<br>
idCurrentScope = [idSearchBar.scopeButtonTitles objectAtIndex:idSearchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];<br>
[self filterContentForIDSearchText:idSearchBar.text];<br>

Thats literally it; It is not a local variable - it comes straight from the storyboard referenced in the .h property

Comment: I dont know how to put linebreaks in comments;  I hope you are able to read that anyway.. :S

Comment: The only thing I can think of is can you post the entire class. The bits and pieces that are there, and some with the wrong variable name, make it hard to diagnose any problem.